# Find out why an Android app is being uninstalled

Tags: android, uninstallation, google-play

My app is having success in Google Play with several million downloads. However, almost 50% of users have uninstalled it already.

I don't think that's a critical number but I'd like to find out why users uninstalls it, so I'd like to ask it to users using a simple form, only to the ones who want to answer of course.

Now problem is **when** to show that optional form. I've seen I can't use ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED because app that's being uninstalled won't receive that broadcast.

Of course I don't want to ever forbid the user to uninstall my app, but I do want to know when to start my optional form. **Can you think of any idea how to do this?**

Also, I've seen that Google Play asks the user why he's uninstalling any app and gives a few options (missing space, don't need it, ...). **Is there any way to get those responses from Google, regarding my app**?

If you can give me any other ideas how to investigate main reasons why users uninstall my app, to improve it, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. The last thing a user will want it to fill out a form just to install an app they don't like. The feedback using the rating system should give you a general idea why some people don't like your app.

Comment: Well every user has a different needs. If your app fails to deliver it, it will be removed because there are no lack of the apps in the market. You need to closely observe this. Visit the blog http://leimobile.com/5-of-the-commonest-reasons-why-smartphone-users-uninstall-apps/ to know the reasons as to why users uninstall your app.

Comment: @BillGary is it good idea to redirect users to Feedback on google store if your app is new on the market. Because you may get negative Reviews and even if you fix them later,  negative reviewers might not come back and your app looks bad even your Version 2 is enhanced. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Once the user uninstalls the app, there's nothing you can do. 50% retention rate isn't actually that bad..

I would propose you look at how the users are using the app, whether it's crashing and how often it's being used: these can then lead as indicators to make an educated guess why they might be uninstalling your app.

Crashes:
These aren't always reported - it's only if the user elects to report it you'll see it in Google Play. Try [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) for a more detailed analysis of how/when/why your app crashes.
Analytics:
I use [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) to log events and work out what my users are doing. You could also look in to some [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing).

Comment: For automatic crash reporting you can now use Firebase API.